# Nuget package dependency being treated as sub depedency looses version constraint

Tags: nuget

Let's say I create a new class library project. I add the Entity Framework **6.1** NuGet package to it, then create a new NuGet package from the class library project with `nuget pack MyProject.csproj`. I get a nice npkg with a depedency to Entity Framework **6.1**.

Then, I decide to add a reference to the GraphDiff NuGet package which has a dependency to EntityFramework >= **6.0**, the resulting class library npkg has only a dependency to GraphDiff and a note that it may have sub-dependencies, but nothing about it being Entity Framework and especially version **6.1**.

Problems arise when I include the class library npkg into a project: Entity Framework **6.0** gets installed while it should have installed **6.1**.

Is there a way around this?

I get this with NuGet.exe 2.8.50926.602

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that I must use a nuspec file and manually specify a dependencies section, like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<package>
   <metadata>
        **snip!!**
        <dependencies>
            <dependency id="EntityFramework" version="6.1.2" />
        </dependencies>
   </metadata>
</package>
```

I haven't been able to change anything working with the nuget project's packages.config file.

There's some valuable information about version dependency on [Rick Strahl's web log](http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2014/Jun/19/Nuget-Dependencies-and-latest-Versions)